I want to make reload animation
My goal is to make magazine of my weapon smoothly rotate 90 degrees on x axis, and then move back. I'm making this via code. But _x value just stucks in 89-90 loop.
Here's my code:
bool flag = false;

if (_x >= 90)
    flag = true;
if (_x == 0)
    flag = false;

if (!flag)
    _x += reloadingSpeed;
else
    _x -= reloadingSpeed;

magazine.localRotation = Quaternion.Euler (_x, magazine.localRotation.y, magazine.localRotation.z);


Suppose _x is 45. Does that mean it’s moving up, or moving down? Maybe it could be either one? In which case, how does your code remember which one it is?

No, _x is 0, and on reload it's starting moving down, and when it reaches 90 degrees, it's moving a bit up and stucks in 90-89 loop. Also my flag also stucks in true-false loop

Note that you use localRotation wrong. It's not euler angles, it's a quaternion and the 4 components are in the range of -1 to 1. You usually want to use localEulerAngles instead. However you should not do read-modify-write operations on localEulerAngles because the representation can flip around at any time. Especially when you're messing with the middle axis (x) as it would rotate into a gimbal lock orientation. You may store the euler angles when you start your animation and use the stored values.

Thanks man, i'll try it (sorry for late response)

Looks like I'm a bit blind, because all this reloading happening in Update, and because of that, flag is being set to false and to true every frame. I just needed to set it to false only in reload key check
